# Simple search - Only works the first time?

Tags: ee2

My users only get proper search results when using the simple search form the first time. Each subsequent search either returns no results or an error.

"The action you have requested is invalid."

EE 2.7.2

Has anyone seen this or have insight?

Answer (score 2):

I was running into a similar error earlier, and the culprit was the template and/or tag caching on the page where the search form was rendered. Might be the source of the problem here as well; if you have any of the EE-based caching options enabled, try disabling them and see what happens.

Comment: Could it be the timeout on searching? I can't recall is that kicks out a more specific error.

Answer (score 2):

Are your users behind a corporate firewall? Sometimes those will include proxies that use their own caching, delivering stale forms to visitors. If that's the case, the network admins should be able to disable network caching for the site.